# Logstash output logs to Elasticsearch server ConfigurationError

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I use Logstash(2.4.0) output logs to Elasticsearch(2.3.3) server.

Before launch Logstash,I write a configuration file `logstash-2.4.0/conf`:

```
input { 
    stdin {} 
} 
filter{
}           
output {            
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

then run `./bin/logstash -f conf/logstash.conf`,the error info as below:
  [image]
how to slove this problem?

Comment: Try removing the `filter` criteria, since it's not used in the above and the `host` within `elasticsearch` should be `hosts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the config look like below, without having the `filter`. You're missing out the "s" in hosts and the double quotes which should go before and after `localhost`.

```
input {
       stdin {}
}

output {
     elasticsearch { hosts => "localhost" }
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

You could check the exact synopsis for the `elasticsearch` plugin from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_synopsis_57).

Comment: If the ES is localhost, it should not need to add this configuration option, since the default for hosts is 172.0.0.1, no?

Comment: @baudsp Yes that's right, you can either have it or leave it without mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks, I had a doubt.

Comment: @baudsp no problem, anytime :)

Comment: 172.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @YaoPan it's 127.0.0.1

Comment: the ES default port is 9200,I add  `output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "10.90.4.9"
        port  => 9200
    }
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug}
}`

Comment: the ES default port is 9200,I add  `output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "10.90.4.9"
        port  => 9200
    }
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug}
}`but it returns ConfigurationError exception。

Comment: try adding your `hosts` as such: hosts => ["http://10.90.4.9:9200"] and remove ya `port`.

Answer (score 0):

according to @Kulasangar' answer,it works well on CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu 16.04,but has the same error on my MAC.I change to root user:

```
sudo su
```

then I relaunch logstash and elasticsearch,everything is well.